# Edited: checkbox check_node won't fire

Tags: jstree

Here is my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/NervousElk/6scrbkex/12/. 
The tree nodes are populated just fine but I cannot find a way to detect which checkbox is then selected/deselected by the user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>testver</title>

<link   rel  = "stylesheet" href="css/jstree/themes/default/style.min.css"> 

</head>           
  <body>                             
  <script src  = "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>                  
  <script src  = "jquery.js"></script>            
  <script src  = "jstree.min.js"></script>    

  <div id="staffallocatertree">                             
  </div> 

  <button id = "treetestbtn" >Build tree
  </button> 

  <script>

  document.getElementById("treetestbtn").addEventListener("click", buildthetree);       

  function buildthetree()
  {     
   //$('#staffallocatertree').jstree('refresh');
   $('#staffallocatertree').jstree(
   {

     'plugins': [ "checkbox", "themes",  "sort", "ui", "state" ], 
     'core' : 
     {
        "check_callback": true,

        /* 'data' : 
        {
            "url"      : "tl2_get_allstaff_as_tree.php",              
            "dataType" : "json" 

        }, */

        'data' : 
        [
            { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Department 1" },
            { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Department 2" },
            { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Dave" },
            { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Jim" },
        ],

        "checkbox": {       
            "three_state" : false, // to avoid that fact that checking a node also check others
            "whole_node" : false,  // to avoid checking the box just clicking the node 
            "tie_selection" : false // for checking without selecting and selecting without checking
        },
        //"plugins": ['checkbox']

     },

   }) 
   .on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) 
   {
            alert(data.node.id + ' ' + data.node.text + (data.node.state.checked ? ' CHECKED': ' NOT CHECKED'))
   })

  };     
</script>     
</body>  
</html>
```

After the tree is populated I want to interact with the checkboxes and detect the node and text for later use. To this end I am trying to get the check_node/ uncheck_node to fire.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Ok, Will work on a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly this seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1266) .
Fortunately the provided answer works, which is to listen on `select_node.jstree`.
In your case, simply change

```js
.on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {})
```

to

```js
.on("select_node.jstree unselect_node.jstree", function(e, data) {})
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks Valentin, Yes I now have it working. Unfortunately this reveals another problem which is the loading of the tree causes the select_node to fire. I want the select_node and uncheck_node to only fire upon user interaction.

Comment: I am not sure I can reproduce the problem when the tree actually loads. Maybe you can provide an example ? Another thing that comes to mind is to inspect the `e` argument of the callback function, which is the event object. That way you can determine what fired that event.

Comment: I'm not doing very well with the creation of a fiddle (the code would be embarrassingly poor anyway and I fear I would be ridiculed) but the good news is I now have the functionality I was seeking. The prevention of the check_node on load I have failed miserably but I thank you for your pointers which have helped.